Counting Occurrences of a Specific 3-Bit Pattern in a Byte Array
I was asked this problem in an interview, and this is the solution I came up with. I was told it's not the most efficient solution, but I can't think of any other solution.
This is the problem:

Given a byte array and a fixed 3-bit pattern 0b101, we need to count the number of times this 3-bit pattern appears within the array. The pattern can span across byte boundaries, meaning it can be formed using bits from consecutive bytes.

int count_3bit_pattern_occurrences(const uint8_t* array, size_t size, uint8_t pattern = 0b101) {
    // Check for input validation
    if (size == 0 || pattern > 0b111) {
        return 0; 
    }

    int count = 0;
    uint32_t value = 0;  // To hold the accumulated bits
    int bit_count = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        value = (value << 8) | array[i];
        bit_count += 8;

        // Check within the current byte
        for (int bit_pos = bit_count - 8; bit_pos <= bit_count - 3; ++bit_pos) {
            if (((value >> (bit_count - 3 - bit_pos)) & 0b111) == pattern) {
                ++count;
            }
        }

        // Prepare for the next iteration, keeping only the last 2 bits
        value &= 0b11;
        bit_count = 2;
    }

    return count;
}

I aimed to minimize space usage by implementing this with O(1) space complexity. However, I'm not sure if there's a more efficient way than iterating through the byte arrays. Is it possible to optimize this further, or am I missing something?

Consider code review if you have correct, working code and you are simply looking for suggestions to improve it.

Thank Drew. I wasn't aware of it. I will ask it there

I suspect that they had in mind processing 3 bytes at a time and shifting the data value right one bit at a time until it is empty (assuming the target pattern is not 0).

@MartinBrown Maybe. I hope that doesn't disqualify my answer for an offer!

I haven't thought this fully through, but I think you can do something with lookup tables. You can certainly build a table of byte values with the number of patterns fully contained within the byte. Then you could have a table of word value that contain the pattern straddling the two bytes, but you would probably need additional logic/lookups to screen cases where the same bit would get counted in more than one pattern.

A byte has only 256 states so you can prepare array of telling in what state whatever byte is regards your search. Then just loop over byte array and collect your count. the whole complexity is that on boundaries also information like did previous byte end with 2 first bits of sequence? matter to determining count so far.

I’m voting to close this question because it seems more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Note that the code produces incorrect results for this, 2 byte array { 0b11111111, 0b01011010 }; which should be 3, not 2.

@500-InternalServerError Indeed, your suggestion does speed up things considerably. See my answer.

As suggested by commenter @500, a lookup table can be much faster than going through the values bit by bit. Here's an example of both. count_3bit_pattern_occurrences() is a sequential function similar to that of the OP. count_3bit_pattern_occurrences_blocked() is a block lookup version that processes 6 bits at a time. This requires a 256, byte array lookup and retaining the top 2 bits for the next lookup. The code uses compile time evaluation of the constexpr lookup array. The block lookup is approximately 5 times faster. The lookup array is 256 bytes in size and is cache friendly.
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

class Timer {
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point snapTime;
    double cumTime = 0;
public:
    Timer() { reset(); }
    void reset() { cumTime = 0; start(); }
    void start() { snapTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now(); }
    double stop() { cumTime += std::chrono::duration<double>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - snapTime).count(); return cumTime; }
};

constexpr uint8_t pattern_3bit{ 0b101 }; // pattern is constexpr to enable compile time lookup table creation

constexpr int count_3bit_pattern_occurrences(const uint8_t* array, size_t size)
{
    uint16_t v{ array[0] };
    int next_array_index = 1;
    size--;
    int total_matched{};

    for (int bit_count = 8; bit_count >= 3; bit_count--)
    {
        if (bit_count == 8 && size > 0)
        {
            v |= array[next_array_index++] << 8;
            bit_count = 16;
            size--;
        }
        if ((v & 7) == pattern_3bit)
            total_matched++;
        v >>= 1;
    }
    return total_matched;
}

int count_3bit_pattern_occurrences_blocked(const uint8_t* array, size_t size)
{
    // lambda to initialize lookup array
    auto init = []() {
        std::array<uint8_t, 256> lookup;
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            uint8_t x = i;
            lookup[i] = count_3bit_pattern_occurrences(&x, 1);
        }
        return lookup;
        };

    constexpr std::array<uint8_t, 256> lookup = init();
    uint16_t v{ array[0] };
    int bit_count = 8;
    int next_array_index = 1;
    size--;
    int total_matched{};
    for (;;)
    {
        if (size == 0)  // if we are at the end of the byte array, decode w/o lookup
        {
            for (; bit_count >= 3; bit_count--)
            {
                if ((v & 7) == pattern_3bit)
                    total_matched++;
                v >>= 1;
            }
            return total_matched;
        }
        if (bit_count <= 8) // keep uint filled
        {
            v |= array[next_array_index++] << bit_count;
            bit_count += 8;
            size--;
        }
        total_matched += lookup[255 & v];   // while 8 bits used for lookup, msb 2 bits are preserved for next block decode
        v >>= 6;
        bit_count -= 6;
    }
    return total_matched;
}


int main()
{
    constexpr int loops{ 1'000'000 };
    Timer time[2];      // accumulate time for pattern counters
    int cnt[2]{};       // accumulate total patterns detected
    std::mt19937 gen(1); // mersenne_twister_engine
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib_n(1, 2000), distrib_256(0, 255);
    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
    {
        std::vector<uint8_t> v(distrib_n(gen));     // generate a vector between 1 and 2000 bytes
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < v.size(); ii++)    // fill hte vector with random bytes
            v[ii] = distrib_256(gen);

        // track time and add patterns detected for each decoder
        time[0].start(); cnt[0] += count_3bit_pattern_occurrences(v.data(), v.size()); time[0].stop();
        time[1].start(); cnt[1] += count_3bit_pattern_occurrences_blocked(v.data(), v.size()); time[1].stop();
    }
    std::cout << "Sequential Execution Time:" << time[0].stop() << " pattern count:" << cnt[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << "Block Execution Time:" << time[1].stop() << " pattern count:" << cnt[1] << '\n';
    // On my machine, x64, opt. MSVC
    //  Sequential Execution Time : 9.4333 pattern count : 999171615
    //  Block Execution Time : 1.90501 pattern count : 999171615
}

